# In/On/Under Another Plan

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositions

Suppose the context is people buying health insurance:

> 1a He is ***in*** another plan.
>   1b He is ***on*** another plan.
>   1c He is ***under*** another plan.
>   2a He is enrolled ***in*** another plan.
>   2b He is enrolled ***on*** another plan.
>   2c He is enrolled ***under*** another plan.

When you talk about people having purchased a health insurance, do you use "*in*" or "*on*" or "*under*"?

Comment: Note that regardless of validity, a sentence like *"He in enrolled under another plan."* is kind of belabored.  You'd more likely say *"He has another plan."* or *"His insurance is different"*.  The technical language of insurance carriers in their paperwork is likely to use the words "enrolled" and "under" and "plan", along with a lot of other wording that few would use.  But *"has insurance with"* and *"is insured by"* are more conversational usages.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases are acceptable.  The slight difference depends on a previous context.
"In" describes membership while "Under" describes protection, probably from a common phrase such as "Under(neath) an umbrella".

Q.  Is Bob in the Blue State plan?  Is Bob a member of the Blue State plan?
A.  No.  Bob is in another plan.  He is a member of the Majors State plan.

Q.  Does Bob's plan provide free manicures?
A.  No.  He is under another plan.  His plan does not provide that protection coverage.

Q.  Did Tim enroll in the same plan as Bob?
A.  No.  He is enrolled in another plan.

Q.  Does Bob get free eye screening like Mary gets with her plan?
A.  No.  He in enrolled under another plan.  He does not get that service.

Comment: I added the possibility of "on" to my question.

Comment: On could be used instead of In, but that would not be standard.